# How to Automatically update build version and Build Date From Visual sourcesafe using Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have developed application in visual studio 2010. I want to show the build version and build date in my application about us form. I want to get the Build version and Build date automatically get update from visual sourcesafe ( version controller)

Comment: Your first move would be to stop using SourceSafe and start using TFS. This is fairly easy using TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, googling will give you more light on your issue

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssourcecontrol/thread/12a1d511-7694-4d5e-8005-ec762dfbdb1b/

Comment: Please don't provide *link only answers*. Try explaining the answer and *then* providing a link to the reference.